# Why materialSkin.2 buttons are kind of fixed design winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

i have a problem when i want to edit a button from MaterialSkin.2 winforms, why this is happening, are they fixed from developers or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the style to controls are fixed, I got stuck on that too, you cannot change colors by editing control properties, only via code, editing the style when loading MaterialSkin.

For buttons you only can edit the Type property to change the appearance between Contained, Outlined and Text.